# How to create a template using the DocuSign API call in c#, xml

Tags: c#, xml, docusignapi

Need help on how to create a template using docusign api, c#, xml

I'm getting an error message as - '(404) Bad Request'

url = https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{......}/templates

```
string requestBody =
        "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
        "<emailSubject>Please sign this Document</emailSubject>" +
        "<status>sent</status>" +                           
        // add document(s)
        "<documents>" +
        "<document>" +
        "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
        "<name>document.pdf</name>" +
        "</document>" +
        "</documents>" +
        // add recipient(s)
        "<recipients>" +
        "<signers>" +
        "<signer>" +
        "<recipientId>1</recipientId>" +
        "<email>ssmith@hotmail.com</email>" +
        "<name>Som Smith</name>" +
        "<roleName>Signer</roleName>" +
        "<tabs>" +
          "<signHereTabs>" +
          "<signHere>" +
            "<xPosition>70</xPosition>" + 
            "<yPosition>560</yPosition>" + 
            "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
            "<pageNumber>2</pageNumber>" +
          "</signHere>" +
          "</signHereTabs>" +
        "</tabs>" +
        "</signer>" +
        "</signers>" +
        "</recipients>" +
        "<envelopeTemplateDefinition>" +
            "<name>TestTemplate</name>" +
            "<owner>" +
                "<email>ssmith@hotmail.com</email>" +
            "</owner>" +
        "</envelopeTemplateDefinition>" +
        "</envelopeDefinition>";
```

The Response error message i'm getting

```
<errorDetails xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">errorCode>UNSPECIFIED_ERROR</errorCode><message>There is an error in XML document (1, 2).</message></errorDetails>
```

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The request body you are using is for sending a signature request from an existing template, not for creating a new template in your account.  To create a new template through the API you need a different request body.  You can use the auto-generated REST API help page:

https://www.docusign.net/restapi/help

Scroll down and find `POST` call for creating a template and you can see a sample request body.  The sample is huge since it includes all possible things that could go into that body, but you'll know how to construct your JSON (or XML).

Also see the corresponding documentation for the API call for creating a template:

[POST Template](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Post%20Template.htm)